# How can I use an existing database with the advanced template of Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installed the yii2 advanced template, and I'm now at migration point where I should create a new database and migrate the app to it.
but I already have a database full of data and I want to use it with yii2 without modifying anything

Comment: just add  the param for access  in you backend , fronted   \config main.php or main-local.php and configure the db component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file

> common/config/main.php

and add the parameters for your database connection

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
         'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ], 

    ],
];
```